# Ramda.js pipe that sets a property based in a previous parameter

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Currently, I have the following code (which works):

```js
const double = R.multiply(2);

const piped = R.pipe(
  (obj) => R.assoc('b', double(obj.a))(obj),
  (obj) => R.assoc('c', double(obj.b))(obj)
);

console.log(
  piped({ a: 1 })
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

However I think that due to that `(obj)` at the end of each pipe function, I guess that I could refactor it to something better in the "Ramda world".

I'm still new to this library, so I yet don't know all the methods and tricks.

Is there a better way to do so using Ramda?

My "real" code is this:

```js
function getScripts() {
  const tryRequire = tryCatch((path) => require(path).run, always(null));

  const addPathAndRunProps = pipe(
    // Note: The `scriptsPath` function is a bound path.join function.
    // It just returns a string.
    (dir) => assoc('path', scriptsPath(dir.name, 'index.js'))(dir),
    (dir) => assoc('run', tryRequire(dir.path))(dir)
  );

  const addModuleRunAndFilterInvalid = pipe(
    map(addPathAndRunProps),
    filter((dir) => typeof dir.run === 'function')
  );

  return addModuleRunAndFilterInvalid(
    fs.readdirSync(SCRIPTS_PATH, { withFileTypes: true })
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to do something with this, or is it just an example you made up?

Comment: My code is a bit more complex than that. I simplified a little. But in the end, that is the idea I need... :-)

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with your code? What's the use-case?

Comment: @Cully, I've edited my post to include my _original_ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be over-using Ramda here. The code is a bit confusing. This would likely be easier to read in the future and more maintainable, while still being functional:

```js
function getScripts() {
  const tryRequire = tryCatch((path) => require(path).run, always(null));

  const addPathAndRunProps = dir => {
    const path = scriptsPath(dir.name, 'index.js')

     return {
        ...dir,
        path,
        run: tryRequire(path),
     }
  }

  return pipe(
     map(addPathAndRunProps),
     filter(x => typeof x.run === 'function'),
  )(fs.readdirSync(SCRIPTS_PATH, { withFileTypes: true }))
}
```

Or, if you really want to keep those setters, try splitting your `addPathAndRunProps` function into two setters:

```js
function getScripts() {
  const tryRequire = tryCatch((path) => require(path).run, always(null));

  const addPathProp = x => assoc('path', scriptsPath(x.name, 'index.js'), x)
  const addRunProp = x => assoc('run', tryRequire(x.path), x)

  return pipe(
    map(addPathProp),
    map(addRunProp),
    filter(x => typeof x.run === 'function'),
  )(fs.readdirSync(SCRIPTS_PATH, { withFileTypes: true }))
}
```

In both cases, I got rid of your `addModuleRunAndFilterInvalid` function. It doesn't add any clarity to your function to have `addModuleRunAndFilterInvalid` split out into its own function, and returning the result of the pipe clarifies the purpose of the `getScripts` function itself.

Also, in your code, you keep calling the object you're operating on `dir`. This is confusing since it implies the object has the same structure on each function call. However the variable passed to `addRunProp` does not have the same structure as what is passed to `addPathProp` (the one passed to `addRunProp` requires an extra `path` prop). Either come up with a descriptive name, or just use `x`. You can think of `x` as the thing your function is operating on. To figure out what `x` is, look at the function name (e.g. `addRunProp` means that `x` is something that will have a run property added to it).

One other potentially useful tip: I've settled on the naming convention of `aug` (short of "augment") for adding a property or bit of info to an object. So I'd rename your `addPathProp` function `augPath` and rename your `addRunProp` function `augRun`. Since I use it consistently, I know that when I see `aug` at the beginning of a function, it's adding a property.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Cully's answer -- there might not be any good reason to try to use Ramda's functions here.

But, if you're interested, there are some Ramda functions which you might choose to use.

[`chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) and [`ap`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap) are fairly generic functions operating on [two different](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain) [abstract types](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply).  But when used with functions, they have some fairly useful behavior as combinators:

```js
chain (f, g) (x) //=> f (g (x)) (x)
ap (f, g) (x)    //=> f (x) (g (x))
```

That means that you could write your function like this:

```js
const piped = R.pipe(
  chain (assoc ('b'), pipe (prop ('a'), double)),
  chain (assoc ('c'), pipe (prop ('b'), double)),
)
```

I don't think this version improves on the original; the repetition involved in those internal `pipe` calls is too complex.

However with a helper function, this might be more reasonable:

```js
const doubleProp = curry (pipe (prop, double))
// or doubleProp = (prop) => (obj) => 2 * obj[prop]

const piped = R.pipe(
  chain (assoc ('b'), doubleProp ('a')),
  chain (assoc ('c'), doubleProp ('b')),
);
```

This is now, to my mind, pretty readable code.  Of course it requires an understanding of `chain` and how it applies to functions, but with that, I think it's actually an improvement on the original.

I frequently make the point that point-free code is a useful tool only when it makes our code more readable.  When it doesn't pointed code is no less functional than point-free.

---

By the way, I just want to note that I'm impressed with the quality of your question.  It's really nice to read questions that are well-thought out and well-presented.  Thank you!